# How to get textarea's text's height with JS?

Tags: javascript, css

I want the height of the texts, not the height of the textarea element. How do I get it with JS, not jQuery?

[image: Highlighed in black]

Comment: @31piy to dynamically adjust the height of my textarea.

Comment: Please read the post that I've mentioned in the comment, and if it solves the problem, mark your question as duplicate of that.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('idOfElement',null)
      .getPropertyValue("height");
```

Comment: this actually just gets me the height of the textarea, not the height of the texts

Comment: @JasmineRain if you want to dynamically change the height of the text area according to the text , then  set a `min-height` to that text area and `height` to auto

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code

```
var element = document.getElementById("elementId");
var size = window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("font-size");
var fontSize = parseFloat(size.replace('px',''));
var height = (fontSize + 1) + "px";
console.log(height);
```